# NLog.config intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense, nlog

I get the following error:

> The global element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:nlog'
>   has already been declared.

And a lot of the following errors with different types:

> The complexType
>   'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:NLogConfiguration' has
>   already been declared.
>
> The simpleType
>   'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:NLogLevel' has already
>   been declared.

I have the following nuget packages installed:

- NLog
- NLog Configuration
- NLog Schema for Intellisense(TM)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After checking in menu XML > Schemas I realized I had more references to the same schema, so I disabled one of them and this solved the problem.

[image]

Comment: Where is this menu item in VS 2013?

Comment: @Jesdisciple, you will find the menu item in Visual Studio 2013 as david.s explains; XML -> Schemas. If you cannot see this menu item it is probably because your current/active document is not a XML document. Try to open and focus a XML document (e.g. a NLog.config file) then you will see the menu item.

Comment: @CasperTaylorKorshøj Aha, thanks. Note to self: Avoid phantom menus.

Answer (score 6):

```
<nlog autoReload="true" 
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd ..\Config\NLog.xsd">
...
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this problem by installing NLog.config (don't confuse with actual NLog) package from NuGet.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Just install NLog.config from Nuget.

Comment: Yeah but what if I don't want the file, since I'm using `<nlog>` tag inside the **app.config**?